# How can i do this type zigzag with css and html

Tags: html, css

I have problem when I tried to get this type of zigzag I tried a lot  but unfortunately it didn't work.

I tried this way of coding

CSS

```
.zigzag:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
.container2:before {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      45deg, transparent 33.333%,
      #E2E2E2 33.333%, #E2E2E2 66.667%,
      transparent 66.667%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg, transparent 33.333%,
      #E2E2E2 33.333%, #E2E2E2 66.667%,
      transparent 66.667%
    );
  background-size: 20px 40px;
}
```

but i get like rectangle zigzag but what i need is like line not rectangle

i want like this 
 [image: i need like this]

Comment: Can you kindly share your HTML also please?

Comment: I would go for the simple solution here: Using a repeating background Image

Answer (score 6):

```
div{
    height: 50px;
    background:  
      linear-gradient(135deg, white 35%, transparent 25%) -25px 0,
      linear-gradient(225deg, white 35%, transparent 25%) -25px 0,
      linear-gradient(315deg, white 35%, transparent 25%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, white 35%, transparent 25%);   
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ay1uduz/

Simply change all `50px` to your element's height, and change all `25px` to half its height.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2gc4g16/6/) here. Hope this will help you.

HTML:

```
<div class="container4 zigzag"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.zigzag {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
 }
.zigzag:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
}
   .container4 {
   background: #CCC;
  }
   .container4:before {
   background:
  linear-gradient(
  45deg, transparent 33.333%,
  #CCC 33.333%, #CCC 66.667%,
  transparent 66.667%
),
linear-gradient(
  -45deg, transparent 33.333%,
  #CCC 33.333%, #CCC 66.667%,
  transparent 66.667%
);
   background-size: 20px 40px;
   }
```

Comment: this one is not like what i want

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div class="container1">
</div>
<div class="container2">
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container1 {
  background: white;
}
.container1:after {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, black 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
.container2 {
    margin-top: -27px;
}
.container2:after {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, white 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, white 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqnD3/637/).